# Can't see tag information in Ask Question wizard

Tags: bug, tags, asking-questions

I just asked a question and wanted to check that I wasn't misusing the tags I'd selected.

Unfortunately there's no tooltip/hover action on tags in the wizard.

Comment: Yes, that behavior is infuriating. And if you do remember that you might need that tag guidance later you have to click in the tiny circle with i in it **before** you add the tag to the tags field. To rectify you have to delete the tag first and then re-try the steps carefully. Maddening ... :/

Comment: Huh? [This blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/) states the wizard is gone. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @ErikA Maybe "wizard" is the wrong term. Feel free to re-tag. It's a difference interface from Meta, though, and it's a different interface to my, er, other accounts which have more rep https://i.stack.imgur.com/E10L8.png

Comment: As an aside, my brain can barely parse that blog post. It's a wall of buzzwords.

Comment: You can just click the tag and see the tag excerpt, right? Just don't hit the cross but the tag text

Comment: @ErikA Hmm, yes, seems I can, by going into "edit" mode. Not too obvious.